# Positioning of Picture

Tags: graphics, floats, pdftex

So I'm trying to put a picture to the right of my text. Following many examples i found on other Problem/Questions i ended with following  `MWE`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./Pictures/} } %not the actual path
\begin{document}
\subsubsection{Arc-Dimension}
    $\alpha=\dfrac{b}{r}\rightarrow$
    \begin{tabular}{l@{$\equiv$}l}
        $\alpha$& Angle in [rad]=$\emptyset$\\
        $b$&Size of arc\\
        $r$&Radius of sector
    \end{tabular}
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=3cm,angle=0]{Arc_Dim.png}
    \end{figure}
    $\alpha\in[0;2\pi] $ is arc-Dimension\\
    $\alpha_G\in[0\deg;360\deg]$ is degree\\ 
    $\Rightarrow\dfrac{\alpha}{\pi}=\dfrac{\alpha_G}{180\deg}$
\end{document}
```

Arc_Dim.png:
[image]

and the Output is the following:
[image]

For Precision: I would like, that the picture went up on the horizontal axis so that it is on the same height as the text.

Comment: You can use two side by side minipage, one for the equations, one for the image.

Comment: There is nothing that forces you to put an `\includegraphics` inside a `figure` environment. If you need it somewhere else, just place it there. An `\includegraphics` will just behave like a really big letter would.

Comment: @leandriis I tried using `minipage` just for the image and it worked out fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `minipages` and a rewritten math part:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % <-- remove demo option in actual document
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}


\begin{document}
\subsubsection{Arc-Dimension}

\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{align*}
    \alpha&=\frac{b}{r}\rightarrow
    \begin{aligned}
        \alpha &\equiv \text{Angle in [rad]}=\emptyset\\
        b &\equiv \text{Size of arc}\\
        r &\equiv \text{Radius of sector}
        \end{aligned}\\
     \alpha&\in[0;2\pi]{}\: \text{is arc-Dimension} \\
     \alpha_G&\in[0\deg;360\deg]{}\: \text{is degree} \\
     &\Rightarrow\frac{\alpha}{\pi}=\frac{\alpha_G}{180\deg}
    \end{align*}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=3cm,angle=0, valign=t]{Arc_Dim.png}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```